# How would I disable one or more Tomcat contexts from starting when Tomcat start up?

Tags: tomcat

I develop locally using Tomcat on my Mac and have several different web applications (contexts) set up under {tomcat-home}/webapps.  Typically, I only need one or at most 2 of them running at a time. When I start Tomcat from Terminal, all the applications under these contexts start by default.

Does anyone know of a configuration option for Tomcat that would only start the "manager" web application when Tomcat first starts so that I could manually start/stop the other web apps as I needed to work on them? A work-around would be to have a separate copy of Tomcat for each individual project and only start that particular copy when I needed to work on that project, but that seems a bit wasteful.